# add custom code folding in vim without losing current folding functionalities

Tags: php, vim, folding

I am using vim to edit my php files, and I am happy with it so far.

I use code folding as well, and it's working fine with PHP functions, classes, methods, etc.

However, when I have a big class with a lot of functions, I like to organise them in #region / #endregion block, as PHP comments can start with '#', it's not interfering with the code.

When I edit a file like that on Windows with Notepad++, the editor recognise that, and allow me to fold whole regions.

I have searched on a lot of web sites, and on stack overflow as well, and did not find any relevant answer.

Please, tell me how to *add* or *extend* the syntax rules in PHP to add #region comments to fold, without loosing the possibility to fold methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

See [this page on the Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fold_a_C_sharp_region). You'll probably have to add these rules to your PHP ftplugin.

Comment: Thank you, but I have this error: "Cannot create region with current foldmethod".

Comment: See `:h foldmethod`: your `foldmethod` is probably set to `syntax`. This tip only works "as is" when `set foldmethod=manual`. When `set foldmethod=syntax`, the folding rules are defined in the PHP syntax file. Around line 419, here.